# Swift - Camera with device rotation in Object Detection

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, avfoundation, coreml

I was looking at this tutorial (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture) and the problem is that when you rotate the device the view of the camera don't change frame size so you'll have a black space.
[image]

[image]

Any ideas to solve this problem?

In addition, I made my version of the app in SwiftUI (but the problem persists), so solution using SwiftUI are also appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how in SwiftUI, but here's how in UIKit:

Try setting the `videoGravity`:

```
cameraView.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
```

Then, this should take care of the orientation. This is based off of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36781371/14351818).

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    
    let cameraPreviewTransform = self.cameraView.transform
    
    coordinator.animate { (context) in
        
        let deltaTransform = coordinator.targetTransform
        let deltaAngle: CGFloat = atan2(deltaTransform.b, deltaTransform.a)
        
        var currentRotation = atan2(cameraPreviewTransform.b, cameraPreviewTransform.a)
        
        // Adding a small value to the rotation angle forces the animation to occur in a the desired direction, preventing an issue where the view would appear to rotate 2PI radians during a rotation from LandscapeRight -> LandscapeLeft.
        currentRotation += -1 * deltaAngle + 0.0001;
        self.cameraView.layer.setValue(currentRotation, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        self.cameraView.layer.frame = self.view.bounds
    } completion: { (context) in
        let currentTransform : CGAffineTransform = self.cameraView.transform
        self.cameraView.transform = currentTransform
    }
}
```

[image: transforming camera on rotation]

Comment: Hi Ahaze, I have a CameraService which is used in CameraView(inherits UIViewControllerRepresentable) which is used in CustomCameraView(inherits View). Where should exactly I should set videoGravity and and override the mentioned function? Or the equivalent of it in SwiftUI? I am not using UIKit

Comment: If you're using `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, you must have a `UIViewController` too — so inside the `UIViewController`,  paste the `viewWillTransition` method, and also add `cameraView.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Can you answer it here so I can accept it as an answer, and maybe you will give more details :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75171252/swiftui-camera-frame-messes-up-with-orientation