# Drawing on AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerlayer

I'm having a video, on which I want my users to draw on the video. I'm able to achieve that. However, when the device orientation gets changed, the drawing gets distorted. The demo source code can be found from below link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkrmqgplgfd53mo/DrawPathOnVideo%204.zip?dl=0

The goal I want to achieve is to allow users draw on AVPlayer, when the video is paused. When the video is played again, the images should appear at that time. Any ready mode controls, if available??

Comment: You are drawing any shape by free hand drawing or you are adding image object?

Comment: I want to provide ability to draw as well as place shapes like circle, squares, etc

Comment: I did something similar, though I've just prevented the drawing view to rotate (which makes sense in my opinion). You can find my question AND my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505772/disable-autorotate-on-a-single-subview-in-ios8

Answer (score -1):

You have to store the x,y coordinates of the shape with particular time inside database.

And when you play the video at that time you have to draw that shape again based on x, y coordinate. When you change the orientation at that time you have to apply some maths for the same.

Comment: What if it's not a fixed shape? I don't want to use database. I want everything drawn and take a screenshot of the screen. However, I'm unable to maintain the orientation and size of the drawn section.

Comment: It's works for all. Negative answer is not the right way for the solution. You can refer iACE app on app store. I have done for all the shape.

Comment: I guess your answers and comments are not that in line with my requirements.

Comment: @HenitNathwani Okay leave it.

Comment: What if it's a bezier path and not a fixed shape? I can't go and store the co-ordinates of all the points coming along the path drawn by the user.

Comment: You have to store all x,y cordinates and recreate the shape from that points

Comment: That's a bit long process. Any other alternative or ready made custom control?

Comment: I have used this code for draw shapes https://github.com/emobc/emobc-ios/tree/master/Classes/canvas